# "Splat" rows with lists into multiple rows (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
user    groupIDs                report
user2   [31501, 31502, 31503]   blogpost
jim     [31501, 31502, 31503]   book
jane    [31600]                 article
jim     [31501, 31502, 31503]   book
peter   [31501, 31502, 31503]   blogpost
user1   [31501, 31502]          blogpost
user1   [31501, 31502]          blogpost
john    [31600]                 tweet
```

`groupIDs` column contains lists of integers.

I need to turn this dataframe into:

```
user    groupIDs    report
user2   31501       blogpost
user2   31502       blogpost
user2   31503       blogpost
jim     31501       book
jim     31502       book
jim     31503       book
jane    31600       article
...
```

That is, turn every row with multiple IDs into a list of this row's copies each with one of the ids in the original list.

`groupby` with use of this column complains about it not being hashable for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick

```
df.set_index(['user', 'report']).groupIDs.apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index(['user', 'report'], name='groupIDs')
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one method. It takes a few lines, but building a new dataframe is often more efficient.

```
from itertools import chain

df = pd.DataFrame([['user2', [31501, 31502, 31503], 'blogpost']],
                  columns=['user', 'groupIDs', 'report'])

lens = list(map(len, df['groupIDs']))

df_out = pd.DataFrame({'user': np.repeat(df['user'].values, lens),
                       'groupIDs': list(chain.from_iterable(df['groupIDs'].values)),
                       'report': np.repeat(df['report'].values, lens)})

#    groupIDs    report   user
# 0     31501  blogpost  user2
# 1     31502  blogpost  user2
# 2     31503  blogpost  user2
```